# Is there a way to fill in specific missing rows in a column using rows in another column as a filter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of car attributes with missing values in some columns. In the `Distance` column for example, there are missing values and I want to replace them  with the mean. There is a second column however, `Car Type` it shows whether the car is brand new or used. A brand new car would not have that many miles driven compared to a used car. I want to replace the NaN values in `Distance` with the mean of `Distance` values where the `Car Type == 'Brand New'`

Minimal setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Car type': ['New','Used','New','New','New','Used','New','New'],
                   'Distance':[20,2222,34,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,50,10]})
print(df)

  Car type  Distance
0      New      20.0
1     Used    2222.0
2      New      34.0
3      New       NaN
4      New       NaN
5     Used       NaN
6      New      50.0
7      New      10.0
```

Comment: Do you want to replace **ALL** NaN values (whatever the `Car Type`) by the mean of "Brand New" `Car Type`?

Comment: No i want to replace the NaN values that corresponds with the car type with the mean distance of that particular car type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the mean for each `Car Type` and broadcast the values (with `transform`) to all rows then use `fillna` to replace NaN by the mean value:

```
df['Distance'] = (df['Distance'].fillna(df.groupby('Car type')['Distance']
                                .transform('mean')))
print(df)

# Output
  Car type  Distance
0      New      20.0
1     Used    2222.0
2      New      34.0
3      New      28.5  # mean of New car
4      New      28.5  # mean of New car
5     Used    2222.0  # mean of Used car
6      New      50.0
7      New      10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['distance'].fillna((df['distance'].mean()), inplace=True)
```

This code above does the naive replacement. Note that the inplace statement makes the original object modified with this change

```
import numpy as np
df['distance'] = np.where(df['Car type'] == "Brand New", df['distance'].mean(), df['distance'])
```

This uses numpy so be sure to import numpy as np. Elegant and fast

Comment: OP comment says "i want to replace the NaN values that correspond with the car type with the mean distance of that particular car type".  Neither of these approaches provided does this.

Comment: This didn't quite work well, but thank you for responding. This could come in handy in my future projects.